# DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Requested unknown parameter 'OwnByWareHouse' for row 0, column 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm working on a project based on an online course.

i'm retrieveing data from the database and showing it on table.
with 4 columns it works great, but when i'm adding the fifth column "OwnByWareHouse"
i'm getting the error "DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Requested unknown parameter 'OwnByWareHouse' for row 0, column 5."
i compared this field with the other working fields in all the  project, and couldnt find any reason for that.
This is the javascript working :

```
function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Admin/Product/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "cost", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "weight", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "inventoryCount", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "onTheWayInventory", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "OwnByWareHouse", "width": "15%" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        return `
                          <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="/Admin/Product/Insert" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                               <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                           </a>
                        </div>
                           `;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return `
                           <div class="text-center">
                              <a href="/Admin/Product/Update/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                 <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                           `;
                    }

                }, "width": "10%"
            }
            ]
    });
}
```

when debugging i reach this GetAll :

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
    var allObj = _unitOfWork.Product.GetAll();
    return Json(new { data = allObj });
}
```

and  i can see the data inside allObj (including column OwnByWareHouse see attached photo with the returned json[image])
so it is coming from the database.
Any ideas? i'm lost

Comment: can you add a dump of **Json(new { data = allObj });**?

Comment: what do you mean "add a dump" ? sorry, language barrier lol

Comment: i added a screen shot of the values i see during debug, allObj retrieved 3 records

Comment: yes, looks like the returned value returns fine, but after the return i get the error message on the browser

Comment: can you add in your browser url (i.e.: navigate) **/Admin/Product/GetAll** and add to the question the resulting string....